# Creating unique aria labels in (nested) for loops

Tags: django-templates, wai-aria

I've a django template that creates a lump of content by looping over some data

The relevant fragment is:

```html
{% for c,v in landlords.items %}
    {% with cloop=forloop.counter %}
    <section class="landlord" aria-labelledby="landlord_c_h3_{{ cloop }}">
        <h3 id="landlord_c_h3_{{ cloop }}">{{ c }}</h3>
        {% for l in v %}
            {% with lloop=forloop.counter %}
            <section class="media" aria-labelledby="landlord_l_h4_{{ cloop }}_{{ lloop }}">
                <section class="media-body" aria-labelledby="landlord_l_h4_{{ cloop }}_{{ lloop }}">
                    <h4 class="mt-0" id="landlord_l_h4_{{ cloop }}_{{ lloop }}">{{ l.name }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ l.address }}</p>
                </section>
                <section role="presentation">
                  <img src="/media/{{ l.logo }}" alt=""/>
                </section>
            </section>
            {% endwith %}
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

.... and this produces some html thus:

```html
  <section class="landlord" aria-labelledby="landlord_c_h3_1">
    <h3 id="landlord_c_h3_1">Council Locality Offices</h3>
    <section class="media" aria-labelledby="landlord_l_h4_1_1">
      <section class="media-body" aria-labelledby="landlord_l_h4_1_1">
        <h4 class="mt-0" id="landlord_l_h4_1_1">North East Locality Office 1</h4>
        <p>123 North East Estate</p>               
      </section>
      <section role="presentation">
        <img src="/media/logo_a.png" alt="">
      <section>
    </section>
    <hr>
  </section>
```

This runs afoul of the "unique labels" rule.... *poodles*

Is there a *clean* way to label `<section class="media" ...` & `<section class="media-body" ..` differently?

I can see a bodge where I hide a couple of elements to provide some prepend content - but that really feels a hack!

Answer (score 0):

For those that want to know my *hack* solution:

```html
<div role="presentation" style="display: none" id="label_a">Card for</div>
<div role="presentation" style="display: none" id="label_b">Details for</div>
{% for c,v in landlords.items %}
    {% with cloop=forloop.counter %}
    <section class="landlord" aria-labelledby="landlord_c_h3_{{ cloop }}">
        <h3 id="landlord_c_h3_{{ cloop }}">{{ c }}</h3>
        {% for l in v %}
            {% with lloop=forloop.counter %}
            <section class="media" aria-labelledby="label_a landlord_l_h4_{{ cloop }}_{{ lloop }}">
                <section class="media-body" aria-labelledby="label_b landlord_l_h4_{{ cloop }}_{{ lloop }}">
                    <h4 class="mt-0" id="landlord_l_h4_{{ cloop }}_{{ lloop }}">{{ l.name }}</h4>
                    <p>{{ l.address }}</p>
                </section>
                <section role="presentation">
                  <img src="/media/{{ l.logo }}" alt=""/>
                </section>
            </section>
            {% endwith %}
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
    </section>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

(not clever, not neat, but works)